# Using Neo4j Bolt .Net Driver

Tags: c#, neo4j, bolt

I am plying around with Neo4j Movie database, starting up the learning curve. I have a WPF app and using the Bolt Neo4j.Driver.V1 GraphDatabase class to talk to the Neo4j Movie database.

```
var mList = session.Run("match (m:Movie) return m").ToList();
```

The above code returns a Json like collection of key/value/property strings. What I want is to go from cypher query like the above and return a List  of Movie objects.

I also would like to have a c# Movie object and convert it to a cypher merge statement to add the movie to the Neo4j database. Anyone know how this should be done?

Comment: Thanks for the link, this looks really interesting. I will have to investigate this more closely. jeiem, thank you, I really appreciate it. I had given up on anyone using .Net and Neo4j.

Comment: No problem, they have some sample code, unit tests and documentation that could help you get started. I think there aren't enough extensions and libraries that are available, so I understand your how frustrating it is. Anyways, good luck.